# packaging with a different directory structure than the source

Tags: python, packaging

How to Change dependency paths and deploy to different directory structure than developing in?

I have a the following structure in my source directory

```
\ABCE
\ABCE\lib
\ABCE\lib\modulA.py
\ABCE\lib\modulA.py
```

if I now package with `python setup.py sdist`

i need to call the module with:

```
import lib.moduleA
import lib.moduleB
```

how can I avoid lib. but maintain my directory structure? So that I import with

```
import moduleA
import moduleB
```

Comment: What is your `setup.py` right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List `lib` in the `packages_dir` option:

```
package_dir = {'': 'lib'}
```

From the [`distutils` "Writing a Setup Script" documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages):

> If you use a different convention to lay out your source directory, that’s no problem: you just have to supply the package_dir option to tell the Distutils about your convention. For example, say you keep all Python source under `lib`, so that modules in the “root package” (i.e., not in any package at all) are in `lib`, modules in the `foo` package are in `lib/foo`, and so forth. Then you would put
>
> ```
> package_dir = {'': 'lib'}
> ```
>
> in your setup script. The keys to this dictionary are package names, and an empty package name stands for the root package. The values are directory names relative to your distribution root. In this case, when you say `packages = ['foo']`, you are promising that the file `lib/foo/__init__.py` exists.